Read the Harmonics in ADE7880
I working on the ADE7880 Evaluation board .I need to read the harmonic registers in ADE7880 evaluation board using arduino uno. For that I enabled the some register like

CONFIG register CF2DIS is set to 1
HX,HY and HZ  3rd,5h and 7th harmonics
HCONFIG register is set to 0x00A8 this for phase-A
STATUS0 is set HREADY is set to 1
when i am reading the HXVRMS,HYVRMS and HZVRMS  I am getting the raw value is   29914,38280 and  33496 like this getting data
and also i want to read the VTHD,ITHD  for this which registers we need to do enable. i am using rish master 3430 meter board for measure the harmonic values like vthd,ithd.
if anyone knows please let me know

i am trying to read the harmonic registers but when i am reding the harmonic register i am getting rawdata is very little bit after that i need to do calibration.
